# latex pmatrix without begin

Tags: formatting, pdftex, plain-tex

I'm quite new to LaTeX, and I'm wondering why do LaTeX use to \begin notation for environments. Is there a way to use \pmatrix directly in latex documents compiled with pdflatex?

I recently dug up [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/latex-math-in-office#latex-in-powerpoint-and-onenote) from microsoft's archive and found a way to use TeX in Onenote, because some times handwriting is more convenient than pure TeX to take notes. But it only supports plain TeX

Since I want to unify my syntax and want to avoid using pmatrix in one and begin{pmatrix} in the other, how can I use only pmatrix in LaTeX?

Comment: Since LaTeX is markup language the only way to write is `\begin{pmatrix} <element of matrix> \end{bmatrix}`. However, you can define new command, which contain `pmatrix` environment (not recommended).

Comment: Over time you'll notice that using environments will actually give a better structure to your code and make it a lot easier to read than adding a lot of stuff to the argument of a macro. Most new users will realise this over time

Comment: Using commands with arguments  you can have some like `\foo{ ... \bah\ ... baz{ ...`  and  later, probably when the above is not visible in the screen, scattered cryptic  ends (i.e.,   `...} ...}  ...}`).  Debug a missing `}`, for instance, is by far more painful that debug a missing enviroment end if the content is some more that a few word or some lines of text or code, except if you add comments to each closing  argiment (e.g. `} % this close the \foo commnad`)  but then, is not it easier write  just `\end{foo}?.

Comment: Note that **at some extent**, some commands can be used as environments and *vice versa*. E.g.:  \documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\emph{#1}}
\newenvironment{bah}{\textbf}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}{Hello}\end{foo}, \bah{World}! Nice to see you. 
\end{document} but beside the surprises doing this  liberal practices (often don't work or the produce undesired outputs),  happens that `amsmath` specifically prevent you of doing that:  Package amsmath Error: **Old form**  `\pmatrix` **should be** \begin{pmatrix}.` so you'll have to deal with it !